# IBM MFP Adapter Deployment Failed

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

Using **IBM MFP 8 with Google cloud platform**,

I have an adapter with many java/lib dependencies, adapter built successfully but when i deploy in MFP Console,

getting **Connection error. Contact the server administrator (HTTP code: 413)**

Adapter File Size is 42MB

Comment: Do you see a problem if deploying through REST API:
http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/rest-admin-api-docs/html/refrest-admin-service-api-docs/html/r_restapi_adapter_post.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope your other adapter deploys successfully, Below are the reasons

1. Check the connection time out on your server.xml for under data source tag.
2. Connection alive time in your DB as you have mentioned Google cloud.
3. If using F5, check the error status and max size allowed params.